Struggling with Distribution Fitting in User Order Analysis – Need Advice!
I recently participated in a Data Science interview process, but unfortunately, I didn’t make it through. The challenge was fascinating, and I’ve decided to share my anonymized solution with the community to get feedback and learn.
Disclaimer:
To respect the confidentiality of the selection process, I’ve rewritten the problem and anonymized all data. You can find the generic version of the problem, code, and visualizations in the repository below:
GitHub Repository
The Challenge:
The task involved analyzing user order behavior, with questions like:

Can we predict the number of future orders for a user (or group of users)?
What probability distribution best describes the number of days between orders?
What is the probability of an interval between orders exceeding a certain threshold (e.g., more than 4 days)?

What I Need Help With:
I’m looking for your thoughts on the following:

Did I make any significant conceptual errors in my approach?
Are there better methods for identifying and testing the best-fitting distribution?
Did I miss any critical detail that could improve the solution?

I’m eager to learn and open to constructive criticism—please don’t hold back! Your insights will help me become a better data scientist.
Thanks so much for taking the time to help. I really appreciate it!

Thanks for sharing your interview solutions notebook. I think your code is nice and clean, and you are using some nice tools like PyCaret which I didn't know about before.
I've spotted a couple of problems:

For the first question, your selected features include

['day_of_month',
 'order_days_last_month',
 'amount_forecasted',
 'cumulative_monthly_transaction_amount',
 'avg_amount_per_transaction',
 'std_amount_per_transaction',
 'daily_amount',
 'amount_last_month']

However when I looked where the features such as avg_amount_per_transaction were defined I found:
    # Average / Std of spending per transaction
    transaction_amount_per_month['avg_amount_per_transaction'] = df.groupby(['account_id'])['daily_amount'].mean().reindex(transaction_amount_per_month.index, level=0)
    transaction_amount_per_month['std_amount_per_transaction'] = df.groupby(['account_id'])['daily_amount'].std().reindex(transaction_amount_per_month.index, level=0)

So you trained your models on features that peek into the future... On the other hand in the same function you do define some correct features that depend only on the past:
# Amount spent in the previous month
    transaction_amount_per_month['amount_last_month'] = transaction_amount_per_month['total_transaction_amount'].shift(1)

and (though delaying by 1 month is missing):
    transaction_amount_per_month['avg_amount_per_month'] = transaction_amount_per_month['total_transaction_amount'].expanding().mean()


For the second question, I assume you had a bit too little time. While a suggestion to model the time between orders using Poisson distribution is a good one, you only fitted the Poisson distribution to a single account's data. Perhaps your interviewers expected that you will suggest a more general model that would be trained on all the history.

Good luck with your job search!
